# Hybris how to completly remove HMC

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I need to remove HMC completly from the project, currently HMC is deployed in PRODUCTION,STAGE and DEVELOP environments too. Which are the steps to remove safely HMC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any extension(including hmc) Hybris offers is available after build and server start because it was specified in localextensions.xml .

Therefore I would suggest trying to **remove hmc specific extensions from your localextensions.xml, perform a build and server start**.

Sometimes , after an extension was removed, a cleanup needs to be done(**hac->Maintenance->Cleanup**).

Do this on your local setup to see whether it is what you need.